# Python: Removing the sections in a list in-between duplicates

Tags: python

I am trying to get my code to remove sections of it in between duplicates. My current code seems to do the correct thing for the first set, but the number seems to skew by 1 for the next one.

I tried switching around and changing the indexes to +1 -1, removing the pop(), changing the range...

```
 user_input = input("Input:")

parsed_input = user_input.split()
printed_parsed = parsed_input


previous_indexes = []
values = []

i = -1
for index in parsed_input:
    i += 1
    if index in previous_indexes:
        print(previous_indexes.index(index))
        first_index = previous_indexes.index(index)
        print(i)
        second_index = i
        new_values = list(range(first_index, second_index+1))
        print(new_values)
        new_values.pop(0)
        print(new_values)
        values.extend(new_values)
    else:
        previous_indexes.append(index)

print(printed_parsed)
print(values)

to_delete = values
target = printed_parsed
for offset, index in enumerate(to_delete):
    index -= offset
    del target[index]

print(target)
```

If I input `3 8 6 5 6 11 7 2 4 9 7 0` I expect to get `3 8 6 11 7 0`, I instead get `3 8 6 11 0`. Somehow the `6` is there, but the `7` isn't.

Comment: Are you absolutely guaranteed that there's going to be just 1 pair of duplicates?

Comment: What if a potential duplicate is in the section that is subject to removal? Say, there is a "5" at the end of your input list. It would be a dupe of the "5" in the 4th position, but that "5" is eventually removed.

Comment: @Ayxan there are MORE THAT ONE PAIR in my example

Comment: @DYZ Can you give me an example of such string?

Comment: I gave you an example if my comment. Just add "5" to the end of your list. And no, there is only one pair for each item in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler possible approach:

```
parsed_input = [3, 8, 6, 5, 6, 11, 7, 2, 4, 9, 7, 0]

# Iterate the unique values in the list
for value in set(parsed_input):
    # If there is one (or possibly none) instance of a value
    # you can skip that value
    if parsed_input.count(value) <= 1:
        continue
    # find the indices of the value
    indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(parsed_input) if x == value]
    # Remove everything between the first and last instance
    del parsed_input[min(indices):max(indices)]

Out[211]: [3, 8, 6, 11, 7, 0]
```

There are lots of edge cases (what if a duplicate value is between two other duplicate values then order would matter etc.), but with the current input this works.

Comment: It needs to be able to process a string like this: 4 5 4 7 4 0, This should output 4, 0

Comment: @DuckyQuack updated.  Should work for both inputs now.

Answer (score 1):

If any duplicated item is not a part of any segment that will be removed, the following code works:

```
# Identify the duplicates by counting all items
from collections import Counter
l = [3, 8, 6, 5, 6, 11, 7, 2, 4, 9, 7, 0]
dups = [k for k,v in Counter(l).items() if v>1]

# For each duplicate, find its position and the position of its peer
for dup in dups:
    start = l.index(dup) # The first instance
    end = len(l) - list(reversed(l)).index(dup) - 1 # The last instance
    # Remove the "offending" segment
    l = l[:start] + l[end:]
#[3, 8, 6, 11, 7, 0]
```

Comment: It needs to be able to process a string like this:
4 5 4 7 4 0, This should output 4, 0

Comment: Updated. The new code removes a range from the first to the last instance.